# Multiple-field GroupBy Linq query is giving same count() value for all records

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, group-by

Here is my SQL query:

```
select sp.TitleEN as ServiceProvider, spt.TitleEN as ServiceProviderType, t.TicketNo, count(t.TicketNo) as TicketsCount 
from tickets as t
join branches as b
on t.branchid = b.id
join ServiceProviders as sp 
on b.ServiceProviderId = sp.id 
join ServiceProviderTypes as spt
on sp.ServiceProviderTypeid = spt.id
group by t.TicketNo, sp.TitleEN, spt.TitleEN
```

Result:

[image]

Simple and straight forward.

Now when I coded the same in LINQ, I wrote:

```
 _context.Tickets
                .Include(m => m.Branch)
                .ThenInclude(m => m.ServiceProvider)
                .ThenInclude(m => m.ServiceProviderType)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(m => new { m.TicketNo, ServiceProvider = m.Branch.ServiceProvider.TitleEn, ServiceProviderType = m.Branch.ServiceProvider.ServiceProviderType.TitleEn })
                .Select(m => new SPsAndSPTypes
                {
                    ServiceProvider = m.Key.ServiceProvider,
                    ServiceProviderType = m.Key.ServiceProviderType,
                    TicketNo = m.Key.TicketNo,
                    TicketCount = m.Key.TicketNo.Count()
                }).ToList();
```

This is what the LINQ query returns:
[image]
[image]

Why am I getting 11 only in the TicketsCount column of LINQ Query result? What am I doing wrong? My application is using ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why developers use `Include` without knowing for which purpose it is introduced. If you have fully custom projection or grouping, `Include` just complicates query translation.

This is correct query:

```
var query = 
   from m in _context.Tickets
   group m by new 
      { 
         m.TicketNo, 
         ServiceProvider = m.Branch.ServiceProvider.TitleEn, 
         ServiceProviderType = m.Branch.ServiceProvider.ServiceProviderType.TitleEn       
      } into g
   select new 
   {
      g.Key.TicketNo,
      g.Key.ServiceProvider,
      g.Key.ServiceProviderType,
      TicketsCount = g.Sum(x => x.TicketNo == null ? 0 : 1)
   }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It works. But, I would request you, if you can point out why Include should not be used with GroupBy in an easy way? You said it complicates the query translations, but I wanted to know why I was getting 11 in all results?

Comment: `count(somefied)` may not be supported by EF.  It counts not nullable values. `m.Key.TicketNo.Count()` - is just wrong it counts character count in TicketsNo field.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Kindly provide me any source/example where I can read about Group By and Include statements in detail . Would really like to understand when and when not to use Include.

Comment: Just remember that `Include` is needed ONLY when you select entities without custom projection. GroupBy is always new projection. Include is just declaration for EF to do projection for related entities automatically.